# proof of theorem related to field axiom

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: If $$a≠0,\mathrm{then\ }\frac{b}{a} =b.a^{-1}.$$

I try to multiply LHS by $a$, then by theorem of division $$a.\frac{b}{a}=b.$$
Then multiply RHS by a we get $$b.a^1.a^{-1}=b.a^{(1-1)}=b.a^0=b.$$ By cancellation law of multiplication we have LHS=RHS we prove the result.

But I want the proof to be more accurate.  Please help me to prove it.

Comment: The axiomatic def'n of  $1/a$ in a field is $1/a=a^{-1}$. The def'n of $b/a$ in a field is $b/a=b(1/a)$. The def'n of $a^{-1}$ is the unique $c$ such that $ac=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define $\frac{b}{a}$. If you denote by it the (unique) element $x$ such that $ax=b$, then
$$
a(ba^{-1})=a(a^{-1}b)=(aa^{-1})b=1\cdot b=b
$$
and so you're done.

The equation $ax=b$ (for $a\ne0$) has unique solution; indeed, if $ax=b$ and $ay=b$, then $ax=ay$ and so
$$
a^{-1}(ax)=a^{-1}(ay)\\
(a^{-1}a)x=(a^{-1}a)y\\
x=y
$$

---

The identity $a^1a^{-1}=a^{1-1}$ doesn't just use the field axioms.